# How Drupal differentiates from url_alias and url path with argument

Tags: path-aliases, 7

I am trying to understand how Drupal recognizes that the following two different paths set in database table `url_alias` are different and don't success to understand it:

products --> node/8

products/bikes --> node/9

so products/dummy is found to match node/8.

Trying to locate the PHP-Drupal code that checks the table, I have found, at "includes/path.inc"

```
 $result = db_query("SELECT source FROM {url_alias}
   WHERE alias = :alias AND language IN (:language, :language_none)
   ORDER BY language DESC, pid DESC", $args);
```

but the variable $args["path"] apparently is set by `drupal_get_path_alias`, which gets the result from the **node->id**. However, I was expecting to see something of the sort $alias = arg(0) . "/" . arg(1)..., etc.

What am I missing?

Comment: Notice that you are just stating facts, without asking any explicit question. _What am I missing?_ is not a question we can answer.

Comment: Why would you think products and products/bikes are the same? If you try to access products/bikes, Drupal will notice it's the path alias for node/9, and it will show that node; if you access products, Drupal will notice it's the path alias for node/8, and it will snow that other node. It cannot confuse a node with thr ID equal to 8 with one whose ID is 9.

Comment: Well, the question is if that is the query used to detect the source (nid) and how $args["path"] is filled and with what values.

Comment: If you look at the name of the function containing that code, and read the documentation for that function, you will find the answer.

Comment: So far, the only thing that is clear is that you don't understand how Drupal can know the difference between products and products/bikes as path aliases, but you don't make clear in which context. In which cases would you think Drupal could possibly confuse products with products/bikes? Do you have a specific use case where Drupal could be confused between two path aliases like those?

Comment: I understand that the two different urls are stored in the database, in url_alias. What I don't understand is where Drupal gets the URL. I am not claiming that Drupal is confusing this, otherwise it wouldn't work. I will try to follow the documentation and the code, but simply didn't get it, and suspect that language switcher is built with node->id already known. This was my primary concern.

Comment: So, to make an example, you visit products, and Drupal shows you the node with ID 9. You don't understand how it can understand it is that node and not another one. Is that correct?

Comment: No, I will express with PHP and my own code (not related to Drupal in any sense). For example, for my particular personal CMS, I would have: $url = arg(0) . "/" . arg(1). Then I check db_query("SELECT * FROM url_alias WHERE url = :url", array(":url" => $url); If this checking fails, I try with $url = arg(0), and I can do it recursively from $url = arg(0)... "/". arg(n) with n arbitrary, and descending towards arg(0), or, in reverse for efficiency.

Comment: This schema works. I cannot see anything similar in Drupal and cannot understand how it manages to get the URL and don't find any parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) or similar that I would expect to find.